# Column with menu in each cell with menu items

Tags: razor, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I want to create a menu item in each cell using Kendo Grid MVC I have managed to get the grid to display with the menu item in each cell but when I click on the menu I don't see the menu items.

Need the menu items to show in their own column this is why I have not bound it to a specific property.

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

```
 @(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model)
.Name("gridDropDownMenu")
.Columns(columns =>
{
    columns.Template(@<text></text>).Title("").Width(120).HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "templateCell" }).ClientTemplate(
            Html.Kendo().Menu()
                .Name("menu_#=ProductID#")
                .Items(its =>
                {
                    its.Add().Text("Actions").Items(nested =>
                    {
                        nested.Add().Text("Test 1");
                        nested.Add().Text("Test 2");
                    });

                })
                .ToClientTemplate().ToHtmlString()
            );


    columns.Bound(p => p.ProductName);
})
.Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell))
.Pageable()
.Scrollable()
.HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:250px;" })
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
    .Ajax()
    .Batch(true)
    .PageSize(20)
    .ServerOperation(false)
    .Events(events => events.Error("errorHandler"))
    .Model(model =>
    {
        model.Id(p => p.ProductID);
        //model.Field(p => p.ProductID).Editable(true);
        model.Field(p => p.CategoryID).DefaultValue(1);
    })

    .Read(read => read.Action("ForeignKeyColumn_Read", "Home"))
    .Update(update => update.Action("ForeignKeyColumn_Update", "Home"))
    .Create(create => create.Action("ForeignKeyColumn_Create", "Home"))
    .Destroy(destroy => destroy.Action("ForeignKeyColumn_Destroy", "Home"))

)
```

)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved by adding the following: `.Events(ev => ev.DataBound("initMenus"))`

```
function initMenus(e) {
    $(".templateCell").each(function(){
        eval($(this).children("script").last().html());
    });
}
```